# Catching temlpateUrl path errors

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm implementing a custom template inside a directive, like this:

```
  .directive('card', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: true,
          templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
              return '/app/templates/' + attrs.cardtype + '.html';
          }
      };
  });
```

The main template where the directive is generated looks like this:

```
<card ng-repeat="card in cards" cardtype="{{card.cardtype}}"></card>
```

Notice I'm using the "cardtype" attribute to select an appropriate template, and then assuming a template name in the directive.

This works fine as long as the cardtype attribute resolves to an html file in the template. However, if the file doesn't exist I get the error:

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: /app/templates/{{card.cardtype}}.html
```

What's the best way to catch this error in order to render a default template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try and ask [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache), whether this template exists. If you don't use template cache I highly recommend using it. You can set up [a grunt task](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates) to scan all your .tpl.html files and set up a template-cache for use. In this way no real HTTP requests are going to get fired in order to fetch the templates.

For a nice example how to use templateCache see [ng-boilerplate (ngbp)](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp)

Comment: Sounds pretty good. I'm interested to know if there is a way to do it without using an external library/tool, but I'll definitely look into this.

Comment: According to the documentation you can: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

However regardless to this issue I would recommend using grunt or gulp for a better and faster development experience. However that's offtopic to your question.

Comment: Ah, okay, I didn't realize this was a core service. Awesome. Thanks for the help.